# In Pycharm debug mode, what is the difference of " step into my code" and "step into"

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

In Pycharm debug mode, when I use the "step into" and "step into my code", they both run the program line by line. So I wonder that is there any difference between these two functions?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

"Step into" runs through ***all code*** in your project including imported libraries, etc.

Whereas "Step Into My Code" skips over library sources and keep focused on your own code.

> Step into My Code
>
> Use Step into My Code to stay focused on your code: the debugger will only step through your code bypassing any library sources.

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/tools.html

> If you want to concentrate on your own code, use the Step Into My Code button - thus you'll avoid stepping into library classes.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/step-2-debugging-your-first-python-application.html